# Universe split into seven different planets, governed by ancient human “Immortals”

Tags: story-identification

The story was about a universe where people were segregated by different aspects and trait of personality. I remember that there were seven different planets (?).

1. One of these planets was the world of partying, where every sin imaginable was OK. It was even the law to take drugs if you were a citizen of this planet.
2. There was another planet of “Wisdom” or “Order” (?) where every person with good logic and a passion for learning and expanding their knowledge lived. Everything was calm and silent on that planet.
3. A 3rd planet was the planet of “creativity”.
4. I can't remember the other 4 planets.

All of this universe was govern by “The Immortals”. The last human alive after the last war, and they've decided to divide the society into these seven group based upon an important person’s study in the far past. No one knew how they could still be alive.

The story was about one man who was at his 20th birthday more or so. I think this was the day you were assigned to your new planet. This man refuses to go where he is assigned so he is send to be judged. And then, at the audience, he attempt to flee. He suddenly bumps into a girl, that was there because she refused to have sex on her planet which was the planet of partying, and they decide to make their way out together.

The last thing I remember reading was that this duo had just learnt about the Immortals, and that those Immortals had just been afflicted by an illness that may end their immortality. So they decide to go on an adventure to learn more about the past of the humans by learning more about these Immortal (the last remains of ancient human civilisation).

There were shuttles or crafts/ships but not for everyone. You were expected to stay on your planet and obey your own laws.

Comment: Do you mean parallel worlds or were there literally seven different worlds?

Comment: The plot sounds quite similar to Divergent; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_%28novel%29

Comment: http://www.eightworldschronicles.com/?

Comment: i know it sound similar to Divergent but it was spread across a galaxie not only on 1 planet

Comment: it was seven different planet on the same univers or dimension if you wish

Comment: no Richard thats not it :S

Comment: yes it was an awesome story especially when they arrive on the party or sin planet where the law say that you must take drug and if someone wants to make love with you you can NOT say no or else you get a fine

Comment: it was that particular planet that gave me the mind pictures about the different worlds, as most of the part i read took place on that particular planet they were about to leavr for a different planet to go and get some more help

Comment: It's also similar to the novel [Logan's Run](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run), although again it all takes place on Earth, not on different planets. It's mostly forgotten now, but in the novel Logan and the girl have to deal with various sub-cultures while they're on the run.

Comment: It is prety recent im sure I remember renting it at the local book store 2 or 3 years ago and i think it was a 2000-2010 story im sure it was a serie of book that was unfinished

Comment: again i remember seeing divergent after reading this story cause i was a little frustrated i thought that divergent took the idea from thos book and then i'de learn that divergent was also a serie of book lolll so now wich was written 1st .. even though in both series the society is divided into different planet/camp (in divergent) i remember clearly that it was spread accross the galaxy in different planet.. i love story that takes place in space :)

Comment: I've added some fresh info that just poped into my mind :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok now i just found it !!!!!

It was a hard one because it is in french. I was sure it was an english story.

The name is "[Segments](http://www.glenatbd.com/bd/segments-tome-1-9782723473729.htm)" and it is written by [Richard Malka](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Malka) and for now there is only part 1, 2 and 3 and it just stop like that. There are no news if that story is planned to be continued.

Even if the link is in french i've post it anyway because this story is worth it. Especially if anyone can find an english copy.

[image][image][image]

This is pretty graphic it is for adult audiences for sexuality, coarse language and high graphic violence.

Comment: The release dates were late 2011, late 2012, and early 2014. So if there's a 4th volume, there's a good chance for it to be published pretty soon.

Comment: @Peter yes I knew about the release date.. i just wanted to know if anyone had news about a sequel cause, on my side, nothing. It's like the story wont have an end :'(